# adb is not recognized as an internal or exteral command error in Android studio

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, adb

My application code is written and executed with no errors. However my emulator will not show up nor does my android device that's plugged in (virtualization is turned on, SDK packages are downloaded, Hyper V is not installed). I get this message from the ADB console:

```
adb is not recognized as an internal or exteral command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried editing the `%PATH%` in both system and user variables but it never works.

I am using the latest Android studio and all the tutorials and answers to my problem refer to Eclipse. At this point I am wondering if I should just abandon Android studio and take refuge in the larger Eclipse community.

Can anyone advise me how to fix it? I've been already trying a long time and I would like to finally see my application in action.

Comment: Did you update the Android studio to 1.0?

Comment: It is the most recent Android Studio on their website.  I just downloaded it a few days ago

Comment: The least one have released just today. You can check on the official website. It do had ADB problem for the last version

Comment: I unfortunately don't have the solution, but if my opinion matters I hope you figure it out and stay with Android Studio. I believe it's a much better IDE for android than Eclipse.

Comment: Awesome I am going to download it and check it out tomorrow.  Thank you !  It has been rough getting tripped up so hard so early by such a silly problem but I will persevere.

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH is incorrectly setup.

For Windows : 
Open up Command Prompt
and type

```
setx ANDROID_ADB_PATH "pathtoyoursdkplatformtools" /m
```

example:

```
setx ANDROID_ADB_PATH "C:\android-sdk-win\platform-tools" /m
```

Comment: I did this and my path in android studio is shown as C:\User\mason_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk in SDK manager.  However when I try to follow this path through my C drive I do not see the package there.  This did not work and when I type in adb devices the same error shows up .  Thank you for the insight still.  Do you know what else could be the problem?

Comment: also when I try to launch the emulator this error shows: Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus_5_API_21_x86'
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!        -But I have installed the HAXM and went into the bios and switch virtualization to enabled.  The code on my app works fine (it's a basic tutorial) but I just want to see it in action

Comment: Be sure to check the sdk is complete and platform-tools exists within your sdk.Appdata is hidden directory by default.About HAXM,you need to manually install it by going into sdk/extras and double clicking haxm-installer setup file, simply downloading it via sdk manager does nothing

Comment: In my sdk manager it says that Android Sdk Tool, Android SDK Platform Tools, and Android SDK Build Tools are installed.  like I said, following the path is fruitless.  I cannot find the AppData folder in the C:\User\mason_000\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk path.  Does this sound familiar at all?

Comment: So how do I get to sdk then if I cannot get into AppData due to it being hidden?

Comment: to keep comments clean, follow this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/show-hidden-files#show-hidden-files=windows-7

Comment: I double clicked on the HAXM folder and then installed the silent_install batch file.  Then I tried to launch the emulator and it did not work.  I tried to update the adb command and it saved bue when I typed adb devices the same error response showed.

Comment: I then tried typing the /m you posted afterwards and that gave me a "access to the registry path is denied"

Answer (score 0):

Identify the exact location of your SDK. From command prompt cd to that folder and execute adb from there. if it still fails, your installation is corrupted. Delete all previous installtions of Android Studio and install fresh. If it works from adb folder , then you are making a mistake in setting up the path correctly.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools
```

this will only work for that particular session though.With respect to HAXM, always make sure the memory you allocate for a AVD is less than 650MB and check the Use Host GPU checkbox.

Comment: adb now works when I'm in Android Studio.  However,  when I launch and AVD I still get the same HAXM error and it does not show my device as an option

Comment: Can you post your AVD configuration here?

Comment: 'Android' and 'adb' commands are working only in D: drive(SDK installed in D:\) . May I know why this is not showing up in cmd (C:\ drive)

Answer (score 0):

You've to set the `adb.exe` path location here.

You can find that, `file>other setting>default project structure>{get your sdk file location}`
Ex: `C:\Users\Spectrum_Developer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Open this path in file explorer and get into `platform-tools`. You can see `adb.exe` here.

Set this current path which is for ex. `C:\Users\Spectrum_Developer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` in your `system environmental path variable`

[image: here]

Restart the system.

Happy coding :-)